# enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-modules, npm-start

I've created a Vue app and started it and worked fine.
I've followed these steps:

1. npm i -g @vue/cli-init
2. vue init webpack geolocation
3. cd geolocation

Then I pushed the code to GitHub and tried to continue to work on the code later in another PC.

When I tried to run here code, I got the following errors:

```
PS D:\geolocation> npm run dev

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\geolocation/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\geolocation\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

But as you can see the package.json file is in the directory...

[image]

The package.json file contains these codes:

```
{
    "name": "geolocation",
    "version": "1.0.0",",
    "author": "B",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
        "start": "npm run dev",
        "build": "node build/build.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.5.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
        "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
        "chalk": "^2.0.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "ora": "^1.2.0",
        "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
        "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
        "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
        "semver": "^5.3.0",
        "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
        "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
        "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 6.0.0",
        "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 8"
    ]
}
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: You may be in another directory containing the path to the file. What is the result when you run the pwd command in the terminal where you run the command, then check the Project directory and run the ls -al command.

Comment: It's unclear what are directory hierarchy and file paths, a screenshot from IDE is not representative. Currently it looks like package.json and package-lock are on different levels, and there are no node_modules, while it's supposed to exist in initialized project